# Passing data from activity A to B : Application Stopped Unexpectedly

Tags: java, android

1.I was trying to pass an array of string from 1 activity to another but the application is giving "Application Stopped Unexpectedly".I am new to android and I don't know how to do it.

2.Can you please tell me how to tackle these runtime errors and how to use logcat I've no
  idea?

Code Activity A:

```
private OnClickListener mylistener=new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        intent=new Intent(MsgSmsActivity.this,MsgSmsActivity2.class);
        MsgSmsActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        intent.putExtra("bodyText", body);
        intent.putExtra("numbersText", number);

    }
};
```

Code Activity B:

```
String[] arr;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    arr=new String[3];
    arr=getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("bodyText");
    TextView tx=new TextView(this);
    tx.setText(arr[0]);
    setContentView(tx); 
}
```

The "body" and "number" are string arrays.

Here is my LogCat:

```
03-21 13:07:03.477: ERROR/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 2<br>
03-21 13:07:14.976: ERROR/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 17<br>
03-21 13:07:17.116: ERROR/BatteryService(76): usbOnlinePath not found<br>
03-21 13:07:17.116: ERROR/BatteryService(76): batteryVoltagePath not found<br>
03-21 13:07:17.116: ERROR/BatteryService(76): batteryTemperaturePath not found<br>
03-21 13:07:17.156: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(76): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake<br>
03-21 13:07:17.386: ERROR/SensorService(76): couldn't open device for module sensors (Invalid argument)<br>
03-21 13:07:43.016: ERROR/System(76): Failure starting core service<br>
03-21 13:07:43.016: ERROR/System(76): java.lang.SecurityException<br>
03-21 13:07:43.016: ERROR/System(76):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)<br>
03-21 13:07:43.016: ERROR/System(76):     at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)<br>
03-21 13:07:43.016: ERROR/System(76):     at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)<br>
03-21 13:07:43.016: ERROR/System(76):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:206)<br>
03-21 13:07:43.056: ERROR/EventHub(76): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter<br>
03-21 13:07:43.056: ERROR/EventHub(76): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter<br>
03-21 13:07:43.756: ERROR/SoundPool(76): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg<br>
03-21 13:07:43.766: ERROR/SoundPool(76): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg<br>
03-21 13:07:43.766: ERROR/SoundPool(76): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg<br>
03-21 13:07:43.766: ERROR/SoundPool(76): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg<br>
03-21 13:07:43.776: ERROR/SoundPool(76): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg<br>
03-21 13:07:43.806: ERROR/UsbObserver(76): java.lang.NullPointerException<br>
03-21 13:07:43.806: ERROR/UsbObserver(76):     at com.android.server.UsbObserver.init(UsbObserver.java:131)<br>
03-21 13:07:43.806: ERROR/UsbObserver(76):     at com.android.server.UsbObserver.<init>(UsbObserver.java:65)<br>
03-21 13:07:43.806: ERROR/UsbObserver(76):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:402)<br>
03-21 13:07:48.077: ERROR/ThrottleService(76): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf<br>
03-21 13:07:48.128: ERROR/ThrottleService(76): Error reading data file<br>
03-21 13:07:48.606: ERROR/logwrapper(172): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory<br>
03-21 13:07:48.687: ERROR/logwrapper(174): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory<br>
03-21 13:07:48.756: ERROR/logwrapper(177): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory<br>
03-21 13:07:54.707: ERROR/logwrapper(213): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory<br>
03-21 13:07:54.737: ERROR/logwrapper(214): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory<br>
03-21 13:07:54.767: ERROR/logwrapper(215): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory<br>
03-21 18:08:58.619: ERROR/MetadataRetrieverClient(33): failed to extract an album art<br>
03-21 18:09:17.207: ERROR/ThrottleService(76): Error reading data file<br>
03-21 18:25:23.387: ERROR/InputDispatcher(76): channel '40517da8 com.example.ssms/com.example.ssms.MsgSmsActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8<br>
03-21 18:25:23.387: ERROR/InputDispatcher(76): channel '40517da8 com.example.ssms/com.example.ssms.MsgSmsActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!<br>
03-21 18:25:31.837: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439): FATAL EXCEPTION: main<br>
03-21 18:25:31.837: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ssms/com.example.ssms.MsgSmsActivity2}: java.lang.NullPointerException<br>
03-21 18:25:31.837: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1622)<br>
03-21 18:25:31.837: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)<br>
03-21 18:25:31.837: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)<br>
03-21 18:25:31.837: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)<br>
03-21 18:25:31.837: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)<br>
03-21 18:25:31.837: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)<br>
03-21 18:25:31.837: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)<br>
03-21 18:25:31.837: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)<br>
03-21 18:25:31.837: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)<br>
03-21 18:25:31.837: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)<br>
03-21 18:25:31.837: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)<br>
03-21 18:25:31.837: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)<br>
03-21 18:25:31.837: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException<br>
03-21 18:25:31.837: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439):     at com.example.ssms.MsgSmsActivity2.onCreate(MsgSmsActivity2.java:23)<br>
03-21 18:25:31.837: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)<br>
03-21 18:25:31.837: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1586)<br>
03-21 18:25:31.837: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: check this in your manifest.xml is there or not MsgSmsActivity2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**arr** is an array of Strings.**tx.setText(arr);** will give exception because **setText** is defined to accept **CharSequence**

If you want to set some text on the **TextView**, then first get the String from array using **arr[index]** and then set that String to the textview.

Comment: sry it is a mistake in question it's arr[0] but the result is same.

Comment: @Mj1992 using Sysout check whether arr has some value or not?

Comment: yeah the problem is in arr it does not contain any values. thnx.

Answer (score 0):

```
private OnClickListener mylistener=new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        intent=new Intent(MsgSmsActivity.this,MsgSmsActivity2.class);
        intent.putExtra("bodyText", body);
        intent.putExtra("numbersText", number);
        MsgSmsActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

try switching the putExtra rows with startActivity.

Comment: thnx @blackbelt for the reply. i did what you said but the result is same :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `putExtra()` in Activity A, try making `body` and `number` into ArrayList's, and using `putStringArrayListExtra()`, then in Activity B use `getStringArrayListExtra()` instead of `getExtra()`.

Answer (score 0):

**Sending string data**

As we already know that we can transfer from one to other Activity by using Intents.

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,GoActivity.class);

String data = “bla bla”;// Data String to send

i.putExtra("DATA",data );
```

**Receiving the Data**

We can receive the above the string data as shown below.

```
Intent i = getIntent();

String data = i.getStringExtra("DATA");// you well get the String data i.e., BLA BLA
```

The Red Colored DATA should be same while sending and receiving the data.

**Sending Object**

Here is the code to send the Object from one to other class. One Important thing to send the Object is the class should implement the Serializable class.

The below Red Colored text should be same.

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,startActivity.class);

ObjectClassName object = new ObjectClassName();

i.putExtra("THIS", Object);
```

**Receiving Object**

// startActivity.java

```
Intent i = getIntent();

ObjectClassName obj = (ObjectClassName) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("THIS");// TypeCasting needed
```